# Encode the url including hyphen(-) and dot(.) in php

Tags: php, urlencode, encode

I need the encoded URL for processing in one of the API, but it requires the full encoded URL. For example, the URL from:

```
http://test.site-raj.co/999999?lpp=1&px2=IjN
```

has to become an encoded URL, like:

```
http%3a%2f%test%site%2draj%2eco%2f999999%3flpp%3d1%26px2%3dIjN
```

I need every symbol to be encoded, even the dot(.) and hyphen(-) like above.

Comment: Your example has no hyphen in it

Comment: @11684 We need to know what he expects hyphens to be translated into. Similarly with the dots.. he just replaced them with percent signs in his expected output.

Comment: Ah, as the question is currently formulated, I thought that was standard encoding.  I already wondered.

Comment: @MikeB the hyphen missed but i am telling that every symbol must be encoded ...

Answer (score 28):

Try this. Inside a function maybe if you are using it more than once...

```
$str = 'http://test.site.co/999999?lpp=1&p---x2=IjN';
$str = urlencode($str);
$str = str_replace('.', '%2E', $str);
$str = str_replace('-', '%2D', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: ya it may be fine but if there exists any other special characters also means how to do it?

Answer (score 10):

This will encode all characters that are not plain letters or numbers. You can still decode this with the standard urldecode or rawurldecode:

```
function urlencodeall($x) {
    $out = '';
    for ($i = 0; isset($x[$i]); $i++) {
        $c = $x[$i];
        if (!ctype_alnum($c)) $c = '%' . sprintf('%02X', ord($c));
        $out .= $c;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use rawurlencode

for example `rawurlencode("http://test.site-raj.co/999999?lpp=1&px2=IjN")`

Comment: http://www.php.net/rawurlencode says Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except `-_.~` have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits. That isn't what the OP asked for.