# How can I store and search for hyphenated/non-hyphenated url names in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

Lets say I have a forum and I have a thread topic called "Game of Thrones"; and its stored just that way in the database. When someone wants to access it, the URL will look like: www.someforum.com/topics/game-of-thrones.

When searching, I can simply replace the hyphens with spaces, or ignore them, but it would create ambiguity between different permutations of words and hyphens for strings that have a both spaces and hyphens(e.g."Mother-In-Law Issues"). How can I handle this?

I thought of creating a "slug" column in the topic table which would contain the url for the topic title, and the "title" column would save the permutation of spaces and hyphens as intended by the user...

Comment: What do you have against hyphens?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz nothing. I would to store the string as the user intended though.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Because I didn't want to place the topic-id in the url. Lets say I store "Martial Arts" I'm going to do a search on that actual string not the id. I will have to add hyphens.

Comment: You just need an encoding that you can always map back. Then encodings are equal if and only if originals are equal. Eg convert space to - and - to --. Or space to Q and Q to QQ. See tag [urlencode] questions. Eg [googling your keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12093050/3404097). You can trade off time for space by storing the encoding vs calling the encoding or decoding function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got you now.
How about something like this (just a rough demo)? -

```
create table url (url_id int primary key,url varchar(1000));
insert into  url (url_id,url) values (1,'www.someforum.com/topics/game-of-thrones');

create table search_term (search_term varchar(1000),url_id int references url(url_id));
insert into search_term values ('game of thrones',1),('GOT',1)
```

---

```
select  u.url

from            search_term     as st

        join    url             as u

        on      u.url_id        =
                st.url_id

where   st.search_term = 'GOT'
;
```